# How to read an XML file using MSBUILD based on a specefic pattern?

Tags: xml, xpath, msbuild

I have an XML file containing the following nodes:

```html
<A>
  <B>
  </B>
  <C>
    <D></D>
    <D></D>  
  </C>
  <C>
    <E>
      <F></F>
    </E>
    <E>
      <F></F>
    </E>
    <E>
      <F></F>
    </E>
  </C>
</A>
```

I'm reading this XML file by MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile using MSBUILD.

```html
<Target Name="name">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="ReadElementText" File="$(path)" 
         XPath="what to define here?">
        <Output PropertyName="x" TaskParameter="Value"/>
     </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile>    
    <Message Text="$(x)"/>    
  </Target>
```

However, I only need to read nodes C which are followed by node E and F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible XPath expression to get `C` elements, anywhere in the XML document, having child element(s) `E` where each `E` has child element(s) `F`, is as follow :

```
//C[E/F]
```